# How to balance work, exercise, and life

Tags: weight-loss

I work from 8 to 17, and I have to wake up at 6:30 to get to my work on time(7:45 to 7:55).and when I get home (around 18:40) I'm so tired and hungry that I lie on the couch and eat and watch TV mostly, and by the time that I want to get up and do some exercise, I feel sleepy and don't want to move!

I don't want to exercise on empty stomach, I get ill every time I do after a week or so and can't workout on a full stomach either!

I have gained almost 10 kg in last 6 months and I'm afraid It's gaining speed in that area.

I need some advise on when, and which kind of exercise.

I'm 25 and I weight 90 kg.

Thank you

Comment: what is your BMI index? it's gorgeous that you start to pay attention to your health when you are very young:)

Comment: seems you spend nearly 3 hours on the way each day, which could be a huge amount of time that you can make of full use:)

Comment: I agree that I waste a lot of time between work and home but how can I make use of that? I tried going by my bicycle but I get all sweaty and smelly and cant't have that! besides no where to park my bike...

Comment: BMI like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index said, turned out 26.2981

Comment: Can you eat a small dinner right before you leave work to go home, then work out when you get home, then eat another meal? Also, what kind of workouts have you been doing, how often, and when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exercise may help you lose weight, but much more important is a good diet.**

You should start watching what you eat. Avoid food high in calories, especially snacks, soda or other things high in (refined) sugar. If it helps you can start to calculate calories of everything you've eaten and compare them with your daily needs.

It is hard to change habits, but you might want to stop eating lying in front of the TV. That would make me tired, too. Let alone the tiring effect of digestion that usually follows a meal.
Have you tried eating a light meal before exercising? This might replenish your energy, but doesn't make you too full.

There are no perfect exercises for weight loss. They should be fun to keep you motivated. Doing any exercise is better than doing nothing, after all.

Comment: thanks for pointing out very serious aspect of my problem.(I'm always hungry :( )

Comment: @tinyByte How much water do you drink during the day? A lot of the times that I feel "hungry" I'm actually either bored or haven't had enough to drink recently (or both).

Comment: can I actually get over my hunger by drinking water? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Can you combine your daily commute to work with exercise ?

For example, if you take the bus/train, can you walk for 30 mins first, take the ride from elsewhere, and then do the reverse on your way home ? A 30 min walk twice a day will do wonders.

Otherwise, can you work out at lunchtime ? Even a 30-40 min walk once a day will help.

As mentioned in the other answer, lying on the sofa and eating is a slippery slope. I struggle with this too ! Try getting into the habit of eating at a table instead. Also, try to make your meals last longer by chewing for longer and drinking plenty water - this will have the added benefit of restricting your calorie intake.  If you are anything like me, if you have "naughty" foods in the house that are good for eating in front of the TV (chocolate springs to mind) then they ***will*** get eaten in front of the TV. So stop buying them regularly ! But don't cut them out altogether - treat yourself from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

One key point for all of those who miss it out:

**If you enjoy lifting, it turns to a hobby which you're looking forward to, rather than a chore and a huge overhead**

There is a lot of mind work involved in this sport same as any other.

Comment: This seems more like a comment

Comment: There is more into mind set than nothing in building your body mate. Your comment looks more like a comment to me than my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a snack in the afternoon and do your exercise directly after work. Exercising will get rid of that tired feeling you have at the end of the day, and you will also eliminate the couch trap if you train before you have your main evening meal.